# Quickblox Audio/Video call for Angular 7 and Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, quickblox

We integrate Quickblox chat application in our project. We are using Node Js in backend and Angular 7 in frontend.

We are trying to implement audio/video call features in frontend(angular 7), but it giving error in node end when we are initiate the call, but the call features not implemented in node end.

```
var session = QB.webrtc.createNewSession(calleesIds, sessionType, callerID, additionalOptions);
session.call({}, function (error) {
                       console.log(error);
                       console.log("Calling.....");

                    });
```

After implementing the call() function error is given

The error is -

```
(node:15945) [DEP0107] DeprecationWarning: tls.convertNPNProtocols() is deprecated.
/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/chat/qbChatHelpers.js:97
        if(typeof stanza.querySelector === 'function') {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at Object.getElementText (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/chat/qbChatHelpers.js:97:26)
    at ChatProxy._onSystemMessageListener (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/chat/qbChat.js:597:42)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/quickblox/src/modules/chat/qbChat.js:817:30)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Client._handleStanza (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js:227:12)
    at Client.onStanza (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js:221:8)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.onStanza (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/node-xmpp-core/lib/Connection.js:377:10)
    at StreamParser.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/node-xmpp-core/lib/Connection.js:231:10)
    at StreamParser.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at SaxLtx.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/@xmpp/streamparser/index.js:69:14)
    at SaxLtx.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at SaxLtx._handleTagOpening (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/ltx/lib/parsers/ltx.js:39:12)
    at SaxLtx.write (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/ltx/lib/parsers/ltx.js:151:18)
    at StreamParser.write (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/@xmpp/streamparser/index.js:134:17)
    at Connection.onData (/var/www/html/boorcomapi/node_modules/node-xmpp-core/lib/Connection.js:310:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! boorcom-data-server@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the boorcom-data-server@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Please help.